# Angular2: import service file path not found

Tags: javascript, angular, filepath

What is the correct syntax for my file path to import my service?  I have a data service that I want to import into my component, it's file path is here:

```
C:\Users\jlz\Documents\Git\Pantheon\Ceto-www\src\app\services\ceto-data\data.service.ts
```

My component file is located here:

```
C:\Users\jlz\Documents\Git\Pantheon\Ceto-www\src\app\querypageheader\querypageheader.component.ts
```

My import statement looks like this:

```
import { DataService } from './data.service';
```

I've tried various different file paths, but none came out correct.  The error I get is my file path can't locate DataService.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it as,

```
import { DataService } from './../services/ceto-data/data.service';
```

You can simply use **[`VSCode`](https://code.visualstudio.com/)**, it will automatically import the path for you.

Comment: Just to add to this answer ... if you are using Angular CLI/Web pack then you want to use relative routing as shown in this answer. You can then navigate to the route using standard path syntax.

Comment: Just a clarification, almost all IDEs will do the auto-import for you, not just VSCode.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović yeah! but VScode is ideal for angular from my point of view

Comment: Thanks!  That worked, how do I use VSCode to import that path by the way?  Do I just start typing and it will show an option?  I tried it, and didn't see anything.